# VSCode: How to get JavaScript IntelliSense working for external File and Git(Devops) dependencies

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

How can I get IntelliSense working for external dependencies from either File or Git(Devops)

We have a fair few core framework libraries that are used in all apps. Currently we make a reference to them  in package.json in one of the following two ways.

- "dependencies": {
  "core-backend-functionality": "file:///C:\Workspaces\Workspace_v2\Core-Framework\core-backend-functionality"
- "dependencies": {
  "core-backend-functionality": "git+https://UK-DEV-v2@dev.azure.com/UK-DEV-v2/Framework%20-%20Core/_git/core-backend-functionality#main"

They get included just fine but IntelliSense does not work for them in the apps they are imported.

Example #1:
In app - No IntelliSense:

```
import env from "core-backend-functionality/utils/environment.js";
console.log(env.isDevelopment());
```

Example #2:
In another file within 'core-backend-functionality' - IntelliSense works

```
import env from "../../../utils/environment.js";
console.log(env.isDevelopment());
```

If I type 'env.' from within Example #1 there is no IntelliSense, but there is in Example #2.

System:

- Node.js
- Express.js
- VSCode

Comment: do those files have [JSDoc type annotations](https://jsdoc.app/tags-type.html)? Or does their package [publish types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html)?

Comment: We have JSDoc annotations.